# Paste clipboard data in Insert mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, insert-mode, register

I have learnt to paste clipboard data (something i copied from web browser using ctrl+c) to my current buffer in insert mode.
It is much easier than doing that in Normal mode.

To paste clipboard data into buffer while in insert mode, try these:
ctrl + r + *
ctrl + r + +

While sometime need to paste something that was copied or cutted from the  same buffer,
try these:
ctrl + r + 0
ctrl + r + "

- I have no idea how to know the data is in registery " or in registry 0, because they moves everytime "dd" or "y" is done. Hence i mapped my  to list out all data in Registry " 0 + * so that i know which to paste using CTRL + r + <" or 0 or + or *>.

Well, i changed these to "contribute" back what i have learnt so far, so other ppl can benefit from my learning too.

Comment: Hello, I’ve edited your question (much like the last) to clean up spelling and grammar. Idk if english is your first language, and we are flexible with mistakes when a reasonable effort is made, but please try to use appropriate capitalization etc. It greatly helps those answering your questions. I’ve also removed your secondary question; [vi.se] has a one-post-per-question rule (see [ask]).

Comment: Aside: I am in normal mode most of the time I’m in vim, even when entering new text into a document. I type, and when I pause I reflexively hit escape. Normal mode is built to be, well, the mode you’re *normally* in. This makes putting from a register fairly easy. But ctrl-r is a really helpful tip as well

Comment: Btw @andrew_ysk Please ask the other question you had, ask it as a separate question. I think it's an interesting one, I think it's one that can probably help you become more efficient with Vim (or perhaps realize Vim is not for you... which is also good in that you get to learn something and look for something that better fits your needs.) In any case, having better answers to *why* you'd want to use a modal editor is definitely an interesting question and I'd like to see it here!

Comment: @andrew_ysk notifications show up in the top (chemie ~ chimie, vous parlez français?). I cant make a yt of my “daily routine typing” in vim, but I recommend you learn the normal mode navigation commands (searching, motions, and operators + text objects). Flashcards with a few at a time is one way. You can find your old question in the edit history of this question.

Comment: @andrew_ysk Here's your other question: *"btw, is there a video on how a truly vim user do typing or editing.. i m not talking about learning command, but how to works by switching between mode and use normal known cmd), i think only by watching other ppl, i can use vim efficiently."*

Comment: @andrew_ysk You'll actually find many videos on YouTube about Vim, just search for "vim" on YouTube should get you started. I can think of authors: ThePrimeagen, Greg Hurrell, thoughtbot, DistroTube. I can't particularly think of one which will address the *modal* nature of Vim, and it's hard to think of one that will work for you in specific... But start watching the ones you find, see if they help?

Comment: @andrew_ysk I'm assuming you're new to Vim, is that the case? From your questions, it seems you're trying to *change* how Vim works rather than *learn* how Vim works. Look, I'm a strong advocate for Vim, so I'll tell you there's benefits to a modal interface, but only if you embrace it. I find it helps simplify your mental model, by switching modes, you need to only keep the commands of the current mode in your brain at one time. It also means you have access to tons of useful motions by pressing a single key, since in normal mode you don't need to share alphanumeric with insertions.

Comment: @andrew_ysk But, of course, that's not for everyone... If you find that modal editors are not for you, then rather than trying to turn Vim into something else, consider trying a different editor that might fulfill your needs? Emacs is a very advanced editor with a rich plug-in ecosystem. By default, Emacs is *not* a modal editor (though you'll even find Emacs plug-ins implementing Vim keybindings including the modal interface.) Perhaps that's the editor you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The Insert mode is discussed in detail under `:h Insert` topic in Vim's help.

In particular, to insert the contents of the "plus" register, while being in Insert mode, you have to press

<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: @andrew_ysk Ctrl-R is "redo" only in Normal mode.